# XAMPP MySQL shutdown unexpectly

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-5.7

I have been trying to run MySQL on my machine of a coupkle of weeks and since using it on the schools system is comes up with the error that it shutdowns down unexpected.

Here is error log:

> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 2018-01-09 12:03:01 6740 [ERROR] Aborting

I have tried changing the ports for loads of different ports.
So what else can I try?

Comment: Where is the error log?

Comment: The D drive is my memory stick "D:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql_error.log"

Comment: Isn't fresh download but haven't done anything to the files. I don't know what datadir means but I don't for that question either. Yes there is a ibdata1 but I have tried deletin this file and that didn't work either. There is nothing special.